# Can Goodberry be used to summon watermelons?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, food-and-drink

The description of the Goodberry spell states:

> Up to ten berries appear in your hand and are infused
>   with magic for the duration. A creature can use its
>   action to eat one berry.

According to the Wikipedia article on Watermelons:

> It is grown for its edible fruit, also known as a watermelon, which is a special kind of **berry** botanically called a pepo.

Emphasis mine.  Given these two bits of information, can the Goodberry spell be used to summon ten watermelons, which can then each be eaten as a standard action?

Comment: Is there a contest you're trying to win? I hear judges frown on magic use during county fairs.

Comment: Can you hold 10 watermelons in your hand if they all appeared there? ;)

Comment: @Guy Presumably, this is best done by jugglers.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl Alright, multi-class Druid with Bard (College of Satire from UA to be sure) and I think its perfectly acceptable. Advantage on perform checks!

Comment: On a more factual note, I don't know that a watermelon can be eaten in 6 seconds (assuming this is the standard time for a round of combat), I'm not sure if stack exchange values "logic tests" in D&D answers, but that would be a stretch for me (no pun intended, which was a shame).

Comment: Cucumbers are for giants, melons for even larger creatures.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, nothing in the spell gives the caster choices about the berries. They're just archetypal berries (because that's what a category word like “berry” means when it's otherwise not specified), so they're *small* round fruits that fit in your hand, as implied by the spell's wording about them all appearing in your hand.

Comment: I guess my only question is "who *does* choose the berry?" For you does this fall under the 'player describes action (casting spell)'->'gm describes results (berries that appear)' paradigm?

Comment: @nitsua60 I got the impression they weren't any specific *kind* of berries, just something that any random murderhobo off the street could identify as "berries".

Comment: @nitsua60 yes, the player chooses if the spell says they can (Goodberry) doesn't, the DM chooses otherwise.

Comment: @nitsua60 Werll, *goodberry* is a divine spell, so possibly a god chooses. Or one of the god's servants. Or the high priest. Or maybe the acolyte who makes the coffee decides based on whatever berry is on sale that week.

Comment: I always describe them as unique, green-gold berries that glow with the requisite inner light 'cause magic; I imagined them as concentrated pellets of healing magic, not literal biological fruits. I don't want my PCs to try fermenting them and selling the healing potion equivalent of moonshine.

Answer (score 20):

### No and no.

#### No:

in *plain English,* the language of the authors of the PHB, a berry is

> a **small**, pulpy and often edible fruit. ([Berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry) at WP, emphasis mine.)

Just like berry, "small" is not a defined term (when applied to objects--ignore creature sizes for a moment, please). But to paraphrase Potter Stewart "I know it when I see it, and this melon is not that."

#### The other 'no':

But as you say, *berry* used as a term of art includes watermelons. Today I learned it also includes tomatoes, cucumbers, eggplants, pumpkins, and bananas (*ibid.*). So, can *Goodberry* produce watermelons? Possibly. This depends on whether at your table the DM or the player describes the ambiguities in a spell's effects.

But you asked:

> can the *Goodberry* spell be used to summon **ten** watermelons? (Emphasis mine.)

**Nope.**
Even if a GM allows watermelon-summons, only one would appear because that's what fits in your hand. (And you'd have to eat the whole thing in six seconds to gain the effect. I'd rule you can, 'cause *magic*, but I'd want to see some serious RP involved.)

Comment: Especially since I just discovered pumpkins. PUMPKINS!

Comment: "I'd want to see some serious RP involved." - since (normal small) berries are normally eaten whole, would you have to eat the rind?

Comment: The spell actually says you can use an action to eat a berry - but not whether you have to eat the *whole* berry; Arguably it'd be enough to take a single bite. Of course, if you take that argument too far, you could end with players licking watermelons to gain the full effects of eating them...

Comment: Hmm... it says "eat a berry," not "eat *of* a berry" or "eat *some* berry." (Obviously, the whole thing's ridiculous, so we shouldn't mince things too finely. There's more than one way to skin an eggplant, after all. Really, I just want to homebrew a *Badberry* spell which conjures pickles.)

Comment: @nitsua60 pumpkins... my favorite berry.

Comment: Mmm, minced berries, minced pumpkins, and it's Thanksgiving in a few days. (Ever try to eat a raw cranberry?  Not a good berry....stick with the sauce).

Answer (score -2):

The answer is probably no, and there's a good piece of evidence as per why it's probably no.  The required spell component for casting Goodberry is a sprig of mistletoe, which, for those of you who imagine the festive decoration, actually looks like a tree branch with long, fingerlike leaves and groups of milky white/pale red berries. Since one of the casting components of Goodberry is a handful of berries, odds are you are using those berries to hold that good good goodberry magic. You're not creating new berries out of nothing, you're just eating berries right off a sprig of mistletoe and hoping that your magic worked correctly because if it didn't mistletoe is somewhat poisonous.

Comment: 'Sprig of Mistletoe' is used in most druid exclusive spells, so saying that the berries are from the mistletoe is a bit presumptuous. It doesn't require a new sprig for every spell cast by a druid (it's more like a focus for druids). Mistletoe is poisonous, though, regardless of what part of it is consumed, so using its berry as the resultant good-berry would cause many to never even attempt to eat them.

Comment: The spell *says* you do create new berries out of nothing: "Up to ten berries **appear** in your hand".