# Can one use the spell Goodberry as a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, improvised-weaponry

The spell [Goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry) produces ten berries that heal one hit-point each. It has a few other uses in terms of nutrition.
Have some RAW berries:

> Up to ten berries appear in your hand and are infused with magic for the duration. A creature can use its action to eat one berry. Eating a berry restores 1 hit point, and the berry provides enough nourishment to sustain a creature for one day. The berries lose their potency if they have not been consumed within 24 hours of the casting of this spell.

They appear 'in your hand', like a warlock's pact-weapon such as a two-handed battle-axe would. They can be consumed at a rate of one per six seconds. Possibly incredibly small, this [berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry) will only fit in a mouth at a rate of one per six seconds - [Lord Crawford Rules](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/697533418813272065?lang=en).

These berries can be of any genre, make &/or style - thus one could have ten different types berries. Also interesting: a *pumpkin* is technically a berry, the maximum size of such a fruit can be [rather large](https://www.cnn.com/2019/10/07/us/small-car-heavy-pumpkin-record-trnd/index.html) - heavier than a car. Still, this is only good for ONE (1) meal. The rules also specify that you can eat that thing under six seconds. If you can make pumpkin pie you will [win the contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_eating) and gain one hit point in the process - assuming such a pie is made [wafer thin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRpt4a6H99c).

Still, nothing in the rules about serving these fruits with a [trebuchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trebuchet). You will want to chill them first because, as the Klingons say: [revenge is a dish best served cold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vwHLMs04XA). [Giants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/hill-giant) with the optional [Druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/druid) caster-upgrade would have 40 shots on hand - so handy.

---

*Question / Repeat:*

**Can one use the *Goodberry* spell as a weapon?**

Comment: Related (dupes?): [Can Goodberry be used to summon watermelons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78430/52137), [Can you shoot goodberries from a blowgun?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123845/52137)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Ask your DM if you can use berries as a weapon.

Technically, you can use good berries as improvised weapons:

> An object that bears no resemblance to a weapon deals 1d4 damage (the DM assigns a damage type appropriate to the object). If a character uses a ranged weapon to make a melee attack, or throws a melee weapon that does not have the thrown property, it also deals 1d4 damage. An improvised thrown weapon has a normal range of 20 feet and a long range of 60 feet.

That said, the DM has the final say, and I imagine most DMs will say “No. Berries do 0 damage.”

#### *Animate objects* might turn this into *Tim’s Stale Berry Bash*.

The spell *animate objects* says:

> Objects come to life at your command. Choose up to ten nonmagical objects within range that are not being worn or carried.

Now, *animate objects* requires *nonmagical* objects, but the magic of the berries has a 24 hour expiration date. It seems perfectly reasonable for a DM to rule that stale berries are nonmagical objects eligible for *animate objects*.

If your DM allows this, then the spell *Tim’s Stale Berry Bash* creates 8 tiny berry creatures that attack with +8 to hit for 1d4+4 bludgeoning berry damage, courtesy of Tim the Botanomancer.

Comment: Does defensive training against berries happen after you learn how to defend yourself against a man armed with a banana?